# splitting lines into lines then adding all to a long list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have some text that is split like so:

line 1

```
hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph.\n, hey I'm a new paragraph. hey I'm a new paragraph. hey I'm a new paragraph.\n, hey im the third paragraph. hey im the third paragraph. hey im the third paragraph.\n
```

line 2

```
hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph.\n, hey I'm a new paragraph. hey I'm a new paragraph. hey I'm a new paragraph.\n, hey im the third paragraph. hey im the third paragraph. hey im the third paragraph.\n
```

this goes on for a while as you can see.
the paragraphs or groupings of lines are split by "\n,"
how can i get all the paragraphs into one list with no smaller lists inside for ex:

```
list = ["hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph.", "etc etc..."]
```

Comment: Are line 1 and line 2 separately defined strings, or a list?

Comment: You are referring to `line 1` and `line 2`…are these lines in a file? If so aren't the *also* separated by new lines?

Comment: line 1 is the first line in the text file

Comment: line 1 and line 2 are strings

Comment: can't you just do `full_list = line1.split('\n')+line2.split('\n')`? your given data gives me the feeling of : reading a file line by line, inputting the raw line into a csv, then reading the csv as text again...

Comment: it is but i cant solve the problem that makes me have to output  to sets of paragraphs to the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text is in a file named `file.txt`, and that the `\n` is a string and not an escape character, then you can do this by simply:

```py
full_list = []

file = open('file.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    full_list += [x.rstrip('\\n') for x in line.split('\\n,')]

file.close()
print(full_list)
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: that worked like a charm but is there any way i can take off the "\n," after ive put it in the list

Comment: glad to help~~! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Splitting the string into a list on the \n?

```
string = '''hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph. hey I'm a paragraph.\n, hey I'm a new paragraph. hey I'm a new paragraph. hey I'm a new paragraph.\n, hey im the third paragraph. hey im the third paragraph. hey im the third paragraph.\n'''
string_list = string.split('\n')
print(string_list)
```